# How to check if the value is present in df for multiple columns and append if not present

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, append

I have multiple df and i want to compare one with the other if the values are same. And if values are not same i want to append the value to the first data frame.
For example: [data frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtwUq.jpg)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mm | hh | jj |
| Kk | ll | gg |

[Data frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBF5I.jpg)
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| Oo|ii |ff |
| Mm|hh |jj |

[Final df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz7nM.jpg)
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| Mm|hh |jj |
| Kk|ll |gg |
| Oo|ii |ff |

Also i want to compare all the columns

Comment: Please don't upload images, format your dataframe into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` to combine the two data frames and then apply `drop_duplicates` method to remove all the duplicate rows

```
final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).drop_duplicates().reset_index()
```